# Scanner de codigo de barras y .NET Pos

Tags: c#, .net

Lo que quiero hacer es automatizar las lecturas que un lector de códigos de barras va efectuando sobre una cinta transportadora (van pasando las cajas y el lector va capturando las etiquetas de cada una).

Para hacerlo, mi idea es implementar un servicio Windows que esté corriendo en una PC donde estará conectado el lector (marca Honeywell, por USB). EL servicio debe capturar el momento en el que el lector hace una lectura, recibir los datos y descifrarlos para luego almacenarlos en una BD.

Actualmente estoy probando con una App Windows Forms, utilizando la librería .NET Pos 1.14 y .NET Framework 4.6.1. Logro crear la instancia de mi dispositivo pero al intentar establecer la conexión, me arroja el siguiente error:

> PosControlException: Unable to Open Device. ErrorCode: NoService.

El código de la aplicación es el siguiente (es bien básico porque primero quiero lograr la conexión, luego seguiré avanzando con la funcionalidad):

```
    PosExplorer _posExplorer;
    DeviceInfo _deviceInfo;
    DeviceCollection _deviceCollection;
    Scanner _scanner;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
        _deviceCollection = _posExplorer.GetDevices();
        _deviceInfo = _posExplorer.GetDevice("Scanner", "1200g");
        _scanner = (Scanner)_posExplorer.CreateInstance(_deviceInfo);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _scanner.Open(); // Aquí se produce el error
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

"1200g" es el modelo del lector que estoy utilizando para testing, en producción será utilizado otro modelo de la misma marca.

Por el tipo de error entiendo que no está corriendo el servicio que se encarga de interactuar con el dispositivo, sin embargo no sé cómo avanzar para solucionar el problema.

Por último, el lector funciona perfectamente, porque hice varias lecturas de prueba, inclusive desde apps win form de prueba y lo hace correctamente.

Saludos y gracias!

---

**EDITO - 13/02/2019**

Opté por la alternativa comentada por @Leandro Tuttini. Logré llegar a lo que necesitaba, pero en una aplicación Windows Forms. Cuando quiero replicar el código en una aplicación Windows Service, se presenta el problema de que la clase RawInput, para ser instanciada, necesita de una ventana activa para recibir los mensajes de WM_INPUT. Es posible hacer esto en un servicio Windows?

Dejo el código que estoy utilizando. El siguiente código tiene como base el código del artículo mencionado por Leandro: [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard) (en una app Windows Forms funciona correctamente, pasandole al RawInput la propiedad Handler de la ventana activa de la aplicación, cosa que no puedo replicar en el servicio).

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private string _vid;
    private string _pid;

    private readonly RawInput _rawInput;

    KeysConverter _keysConverter;
    private string _datosLeidos;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _vid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LectorVID"]; // Para escuchar únicamente mi lector e ignorar el resto de teclados
        _pid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LectorPID"]; // Para escuchar únicamente mi lector e ignorar el resto de teclados

        _rawInput = new RawInput(new IntPtr(), captureOnlyInForeground: false); // No sé qué valor pasar para el primer parámetro

        _keysConverter = new KeysConverter();
        _datosLeidos = String.Empty;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Win32.DeviceAudit();

        _rawInput.KeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _rawInput.KeyPressed -= OnKeyPressed;
    }

    private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, RawInputEventArg e)
    {
        if (e.KeyPressEvent.Message != Win32.WM_KEYUP)
            return;

        if (e.KeyPressEvent.VKeyName.ToUpper() == "ENTER")
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Resultado.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(String.Format("Código leído: {0}", _datosLeidos));
            }

            _datosLeidos = String.Empty;

            return;
        }

        if (e.KeyPressEvent.DeviceName.ToUpper().Contains(_vid)
                && e.KeyPressEvent.DeviceName.ToUpper().Contains(_pid))
        {
            _datosLeidos += _keysConverter.ConvertToString(e.KeyPressEvent.VKey);
        }
    }
```

---

**EDITO 2**

SOLUCIONADO: en lugar de utilizar un servicio Windows, utilizo la aplicación Windows Forms ocultando toda interfaz para que nadie pueda cerrar la app. Luego programaré el inicio del SO para que arranque la app, simulando el funcionamiento de un servicio.

El único inconveniente que queda es evitar que al realizar una lectura desde el lector, no se escriban los datos en el control activo, pero eso ya debe ser configuración del lector y correspondería a otra pregunta.

Gracias!

Comment: este lector actua como un teclado? digo si lo conectas a la pc y pones el foco en el notepad o word, al realizar la lectura lee correctamente el codigo ? descartemos que el lector funcione correctamente. Porque quizas si funciona podrias hacer que el servicio de windows capture las entradas por teclado global de la pc y por ende las del lector

Comment: has probado conectarlo por el puerto serial RS232?, te dejo el manual del mismo. https://aidc.honeywell.com/CatalogDocuments/VG1200-UG.pdf yo conecte un scanner symbol y funciona correctamente, espero que te ayude en algo.

Comment: Leandro: si, el lector funciona correctamente, lo probé desde word y lee correctamente los codigos. Lo de capturarlo como teclado es posible aun si la pc se usa para otea cosa? O sea, el teclado real se estaría usando en simultaneo.

Comment: Como bien te comenta @LeandroTuttini, los lectores de código de barras habitualmente actúan exactamente igual que un teclado. No es necesaria absolutamente ninguna librería. Puedes probarlo de una manera muy sencilla, crea un formulario con un textbox, ejecuta la aplicación, colocate en el textbox y lee un codigo de barras. Verás como funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Si tienes ambos conectados quizas debas agregar logica en el codigo que permita diferenciar que valores ingresa, si se realiza una lectua y se escribe simutanamente en el input ingresaran datos mezclados, se supone que la pc que realiza la lectura no debria utilizar un teclado, no al menos al mismo tiempo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Entiendo perfectamente lo que comentas, por eso estoy buscando la forma de "escuchar" el puerto USB en el que está conectado el lector, para manejar eso separado del resto de lo que se haga en la PC en simultaneo.

Comment: @Pikoh entiendo como funcionan los lector, y este funciona correctamente. Pero necesito hacer esto sin una interfaz, porque el lector dispara las lecturas automaticamente, y yo necesito interceptarlas. El uso de una interfaz no es posible porque la PC se estaría usando en simultaneo para otra cosa.

Comment: @Manny gracias por el documento, voy a probar a ver que consigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizas no se simple de implementar ya que requiere trabajar con las `api de windows`, pero podrias usar el `hook global` del `keyboard`, este permite diferenciar cual es el dispositivo que realiza la accion.

[Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard)

Usando el [RegisterRawInputDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600%28VS.85%29.aspx) para registrar el keyboard y monitoreando el mensaje WM_INPUT se podria determinar el dispositivo desde el cual viene el input

No pongo codigo porque basicamente seria usar las api de windows, pero seria una alternativa para analizar.

Comment: Opté por esta alternativa y conseguí justo lo que necesitaba, pero sólo pude hacerlo en una aplicación Windows Forms. Cuando quiero replicar la lógica en un Windows Service, se presenta el inconveniente de que la clase RawInput, para ser instanciada, necesita de una ventana activa para recibir los mensajes de WM_INPUT, pero al ser un servicio, no tengo ventana. Entonces me surge la duda de si es posible desarrollar esta funcionalidad en un servicio windows? Actualizo la pregiunta con el código fuente que estoy utilizando

Answer (score 0):

> en producción será utilizado otro modelo de la misma marca.

Revisa los SDK con detenimiento. Podría darse el caso que ambos modelos tengan diferentes SDKs.

¿Has descargado el PSO para .net SDK 1.12 o 1.14? Los links están a continuación:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5355
- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42081

¿Qué sucede al usar la aplicación de ejemplo que viene con el SDK? ¿Abre la comunicación con el dispositivo?

Respuesta parcialmente extraída y traducida de https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ca8d5ffa-d896-42dc-84ad-8a4f00ee77c3/pos4net-honeywell-voyager-1202g-problem

Comment: Probé con la versión 1.12, pero entonces tuve que bajar la versión del Framework utilizada a la 3.0. En dicha versión no aparece mi dispositivo en la lista de "DeviceInfoCollection". Con la aplicación de ejemplo sucede lo mismo, obtengo el mismo error. Por eso entiendo que el problema está por fuera de mi app (la que yo estoy desarrollando).

Comment: En ese caso, existe la posibilidad que el dispositivo tenga fallas. Hace años trabajando con un lector de código de barras, hubo un problema con un equipo: leía mal los códigos.